# Empty check of optional parameter fails

Tags: php, string, parameters

I have implemented a function in a singleton class with an optional parameter.

```
private function MyFunction($Name = "")
{

$localCopy = $Name;

//this check fails, EMPTY is printed!
if (empty($Name))
  echo "EMPTY";
else
  echo "NOT EMPTY";

//this is working, NOT EMPTY is printed
if (empty($localCopy))
  echo "EMPTY";
else
  echo "NOT EMPTY";

}
```

This function is called by another function in the same class.

```
public function OtherFunction($Name = '')
{
   self::MyFunction($Name);
}
```

OtherFunction is called from outside

```
OtherFunction("Hello");
```

Why does the empty check only works correctly with the local copy?
Can someone explain me this??

Comment: It must be something your server, settings, etc. I tried out the code, and it worked like it should do for me. When empty it outputted "EMPTY EMPTY" when not empty "NOT EMPTY NOT EMPTY"

Answer (score 0):

No. Both variables

```
$Name
```

and

```
$localCopy
```

shouldn't be distinguishable. Both point to the same 'thing'.

Moreover, `$localCopy` often **isn't a copy**, just a second name for the thing `$name` denotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Damn!!

I have used a mix of $Name and $name in my code. Two different variables!!!
An unassigned variable was used....

What an ugly thing for people coming from C/C++/C# :(  Now warning, no error.... :)